# How to use two header information when using ui.router?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs' ui.router and have two templates view for routing. Therefore, I just have one `<head></head>` information on index.html

However, I want to apply to different series header meta property and value information to those two templates. For example, t`<meta property="og:title" content="Something1">` to template 1 and  `<meta property="og:title" content="Something2">` to template 2.

Are there any ways I can do it but still using ui.router rather than separating them in two independent pages?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/tinusn/ui-router-metatags

Answer (score 1):

Use `$rootScope` variable for it.

**main.js:**

```
$rootScope.metatags = {
    content: 'Default content'
};
```

**Something1 Controller:**

```
$rootScope.metatags.content = 'Something1';
```

**Something2 Controller:**

```
$rootScope.metatags.content = 'Something2';
```

**index.html:**

```
<head>
    // something
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{metatags.content}}">
</head>
```

Comment: I tried it on facebook WebMaster on ' property="og:title" ', but it can't parse {{metatags.content}} (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters). In addition, if I use $rootScope, all my pages' scope seems interrupt, all "{{}}" expression can't be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Same idea with @WorkWe of using `$rootScope` but instead of putting the meta tags information on the controller, you could pass it as the value of the `data object` that is an optional property when defining a new state. See [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) for more information.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        data: {
            metatags: { title: 'Something1' }
        }
    })
    .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'about.html',
        data: {
            metatags: { title: 'Something2' }
        }
    });
```

And in your app.js, assign it to some $rootScope property

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ui.router'])
    .run(function($rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            if(angular.isDefined(toState.data) && angular.isDefined(toState.data.metatags)) {
                $rootScope.metatags = toState.data.metatags;
            } else {
                $rootScope.metatags = { title: 'Your default meta title content' };
            }
        });
    });
```

Lastly, in your html file:

```
<head>
    <meta name="og:title" content="{{ metatags.title }}">
</head>
```